# Linux terminal-based CSV or TSV editor - command-line Calc?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, terminal

I'm trying to find a command line editor (or vim plugin) for large CSV or TSV files that will fix the width of cells and keep the row and column headers in view so I can move between cells and edit data.  Basically something like the old DOS versions of Lotus 123 or Quattro Pro.

I find myself continually doing quick fixes in tabular data and don't want to fire up Calc every single time I want to change a few cells in column 32.  I am not looking for perl/awk solutions since most of the fixes are one-off spelling/case data entry errors.

Comment: I don't know how to do the tab width fixing but ':1split' will give you a horizontal split window 1 line in size to keep the headers in view.  Then Ctrl W-W will toggle you between the windows in VIM

Comment: Just found macrocalc - looks interesting.

Comment: @hurfdurf can you provide a link to the macrocalc you have found?

Comment: Here's the link to macrocalc: http://www.freakout.de/#download

Answer (score 3):

Take a look onto [sc](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sc) or [Gnu Oleo](http://www.gnu.org/software/oleo/), the may fit your need's

Also a look onto the [Emacs based Spreadsheets](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpreadSheet) may be worth a look

cheerio 
   Steve

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could use vim with ts/sw and friends to set up your columns widths, and then :1split to keep headers in view.  You can also (assuming your CSV data doesn't have tabs in it already) do something like:

```
%s/,/\t/g
```

to switch commas to tabs, and

```
%s/\t/,/g
```

to switch them back, since it's easier to format TSV than CSV.

Comment: +1 You can do *anything* in Vim ;-).

Comment: @sleske, anything? Then why do we fill our machines with thousands of different programs for different purposes. If I've said it once I've said it a billion times - don't exaggerate.

Comment: As far as I know, http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/areas/classics/eliza/emacs/doctor.el has never been put into vim.  But otherwise, yep!

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294 (Align) looks like it could be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest emeditor through wine